# restframework-jwt not working with manual model class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have only beginner level idea about django restframework-jwt. When i try to authenticate with my custom model class it showing

> "non_field_errors": [
>           "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
>       ]

But I can generate token with "**auth_user**" table data

model.py contain users class & user_manager

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework_jwt',
'rest_framework.authtoken', 
 ]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = '**app_name**.Users'
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
)
}

JWT_AUTH = {

'JWT_VERIFY': True,
'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=3000),
'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your settings.py file like this :

Also add new app in INSTALLED_APPS and add AUTH_USER_MODEL

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework_jwt',
'app_name'
 ]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = '**app_name**.Users'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (        
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}


JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,

}
```

Comment: did you do migrating actions?

Comment: yes.i cant upload my model class here due to its length site blocking. that contain Users(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin) and class UserManager(BaseUserManager): is there will any mistake?

Comment: and also do migrating actions

Comment: did but same message